# How to make SQL query having many JOIN statements shorter and quicker?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a lot of INNER JOINS to make which actually take very long time to execute. Is there another way I can do this? Quicker and perhaps shorter?

```
SELECT fermat.*,  .... -- around 17 other tables FROM fermat 

INNER JOIN bla_bla on ....
-- around 17 other INNER JOINS
```

Comment: What is the rest of your query?  What do you want to make quicker and shorter -- execution time or # characters of your `SQL`?

Comment: For fast execution of the query you should have to create index on joins table. It Might helps to you.

Comment: what @JogiMehul said. This type of query is going to be all about index and column optimization

Comment: You either need all those tables or you don't. There is not really an alternative to joining tables.

Comment: I highly recommend reading through http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql to learn how indexes work and can be used best.

Comment: To optimize, make sure all the tables are properly indexed and you use unique or primary keys when you can, but linking a million tables together is not a good idea.  Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you would want to make it more modular, or at that point, create a table which is populated on Trigger that you can accesss later.

Comment: Show us the entire query and then we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is no. If you need to use all of the tables then you need to join all the tables. So there isn't really any way to drastically increase performance in the query. A minor change which I can see in your query is to only select the columns you need from tables and avoiding using `table.*` when you aren't using all the columns.

However, optimising the tables could help. To increase performance you can make sure indexes are set up on every column you're joining on.

Since we can't see your whole query there may be a bottleneck elsewhere. In MySQL you can do `EXPLAIN SELECT...` which show your planned execution path. This is very helpful when debugging or trying to find bottlenecks.